# Putting Google Analytics to the server

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

As you know, when using Google Analytics, you'll embed a snippet of JS into your page's HEAD.

But all it seems to do is sent data to Google about a visit, or something. So I wonder, if there is a way to do that same thing from within Express? Basically, a middleware that picks up the request and sends the same data to Google than the browser would.

The advantage would clearly be, that the user's browser doesn't have to bother with loading more JS than it really needs.

I have an Analytics Key - this `UA-XXXX-XX` token. Now I just want to track from my server, instead of client.

Comment: you can send data to google analytics from where ever you like  directly using the Measurement protocol https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/?hl=en

Comment: @DaImTo Nice! Do you happen to know of a convenient module, or will I have to code it myself? I'd like to avoid writing something that may already exist.